Implement DownstreamApi in a project .net framework 4.8 with OWIN and AutoFac
I need to implement the method
.AddDownstreamApi("DownstreamApi", builder.Configuration.GetSection(""))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

in a project with a .net framework 4.8 with OWIN and Autofac.
I have to implement these methods because I have a service that needs the ITokenAcquisition interface to instantiate it. Do you have any ideas on how to do it?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
